# SQL query to search for patterns against a specific string

Tags: sql-server, regex, matching

I am currently dealing with a table containing a list of hundreds of part number patterns for discount purposes.
For example:

```
1) [FR]08-[01237]0[67]4E-%
2) _10-[01]064[CD]-____
3) F12-[0123]0[67]4C-%
```

I have a string search criteria: F10-1064C-02TY and I am trying to find out which pattern(s) matches that particular string. For this example my query would return the second pattern. The objective is to find the correct part discount based on the matched pattern(s).

What is the best approach in handling this type of problem? Is there a simple and elegant approach or does this involve some complex TSQL procedure?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex, only pattern matching, by using operators such as `LIKE`. [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Have you made any attempts so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern for the right side of a LIKE clause can be any expression, which includes values from a table. This means you can use your patterns table in a query i.e.

```
SELECT PatternId, Pattern
FROM Patterns
WHERE 'F10-1064C-02TY' LIKE Pattern
```

You can build from here - if your part numbers are stored in a different table, join to that table using the LIKE clause as a join criterion, or build a procedure that takes a part number parameter, or whatever else fits your requirements.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!